# How to find the culprit of high sysload on NAS?

Tags: linux, command-line, nas, high-cpu-usage

I have a QNAP TS-410 NAS, modest little ARM-based box.

In the past the sysload of the NAS would be well below 0.5 for all load averages (1, 5 and 15 mins), it would only spike while sabnzbd was downloading/repairing/unraring and then go back to normal.

Recently though, the load average is consistently > 2 and I want to find what's causing it and have no idea where to start, I'm a beginner at Linux.

Can someone assist me in running any commands that would help me isolate what's the culprit here?

I've run `top` and this is a snapshot:

[image: Snapshot]

Any help would be great.

Thanks

EDIT:

I typed vmstat as requested below but the command wasn't found but after Googling, I see there's a file called `/proc/vmstat`, here's the output from doing `cat /proc/vmstat`

```
[~] # cat /proc/vmstat 
nr_free_pages 5642
nr_inactive_anon 3992
nr_active_anon 2216
nr_inactive_file 12771
nr_active_file 8037
nr_unevictable 562
nr_mlock 562
nr_anon_pages 4865
nr_mapped 1979
nr_file_pages 23224
nr_dirty 7
nr_writeback 0
nr_slab_reclaimable 3267
nr_slab_unreclaimable 3384
nr_page_table_pages 768
nr_kernel_stack 200
nr_unstable 0
nr_bounce 0
nr_vmscan_write 9804
nr_vmscan_immediate_reclaim 19
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_isolated_anon 0
nr_isolated_file 0
nr_shmem 98
nr_dirtied 1721606
nr_written 1324463
nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 0
nr_dirty_threshold 1274
nr_dirty_background_threshold 637
pgpgin 2596318
pgpgout 4735932
pswpin 3304
pswpout 9749
pgalloc_normal 27675644
pgalloc_movable 0
pgfree 27681348
pgactivate 406093
pgdeactivate 124873
pgfault 51190288
pgmajfault 7969
pgrefill_normal 131208
pgrefill_movable 0
pgsteal_kswapd_normal 1198951
pgsteal_kswapd_movable 0
pgsteal_direct_normal 129004
pgsteal_direct_movable 0
pgscan_kswapd_normal 1221226
pgscan_kswapd_movable 0
pgscan_direct_normal 136485
pgscan_direct_movable 0
pginodesteal 54
slabs_scanned 2078336
kswapd_inodesteal 1461
kswapd_low_wmark_hit_quickly 1
kswapd_high_wmark_hit_quickly 84
kswapd_skip_congestion_wait 141
pageoutrun 25960
allocstall 2800
pgrotated 9781
unevictable_pgs_culled 698
unevictable_pgs_scanned 0
unevictable_pgs_rescued 765
unevictable_pgs_mlocked 1327
unevictable_pgs_munlocked 765
unevictable_pgs_cleared 0
unevictable_pgs_stranded 0
unevictable_pgs_mlockfreed 0
```

Not sure if this is what was needed?

Comment: does the box have "vmstat" command? if so, could you run "vmstat 5" for a minute and post output?

Comment: I'm not sure, will try to run that command and will post back in a couple of hours.

Comment: I've edited the post, please have a look.

Comment: This may be due to short-lived processes that are unlikely to show in `ps` or `top`. Unfortunately, your NAS is probably not equipped to debug this problem, for example [like this](http://www.howtoslinux.org/news/fedora-news/5570-lukas-lzap-zapletal-track-short-lived-processes-with-auditd).

Comment: I guess I'll have to try the QNAP forum then, maybe someone there has an idea.

Comment: @Fayyaadh it does not really help, sorry... while vmstat(1) is partly related to parsing /proc/vmstat, it also parses /proc/stat and /proc/meminfo; and it is not their current values that are interesting (which you pasted), but their changes in some fixed time interval over time